# How do I migrate my postgres data from 8.4 to 9.1?

Tags: postgresql

I have upgraded my ubuntu development machine from 11.04 to 11.10.
In the process my postgres was also upgraded from 8.4 to 9.1.

But I seem to have lost all my data. If I look, I can see that my data for 8.4 is in folder `/var/lib/postgres/8.4/main` and my new database is in `/var/lib/postgres/9.1/main`.

What is the best way to migrate my data to the new version? Can I just copy the files?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
su postgres
pg_dropcluster --stop 9.1 main    
pg_upgradecluster 8.4 main
```

At first this did not work for me for two reasons. Firstly, postgresql-8.4 had been unistalled at some point, so I had to reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-8.4
```

Then I had to go into the 8.4 `postgresql.conf` and change `max_connections` to 10. Then it worked. You should be able to find the conf file at `/etc/postgresql/8.4/main/postgresql.conf`

Comment: On one computer the top three lines were enough. On the other I had to reinstall 8.4 to make it work, as you said. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It should be noted that the "pg_upgradecluster" script doesn't handle the case where the database user must be supplied. (If it does, I sure can't figure out how to provide it.)

Comment: If you get `Error: specified cluster is not running` when trying again after having changed `max_connections`, use `pg_ctlcluster 8.4 main start`.

Comment: Reducing `max_connections` did not work for me. As an alternative solution provided by the error message, I reduced `shared_buffers` to 20MB (from 200MB), which worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

After upgrading to 11.10, the PostgreSQL 9.1 was installed, but the running version was 8.4.

I've tried:

```
su postgres
pg_dropcluster --stop 9.1 main    
pg_upgradecluster 8.4 main
```

It reported the error:

```
Stopping old cluster...
pg_ctl: servidor não desligou
Error: Could not stop old cluster
```

So, in another window:

```
$ sudo service postgresql-8.4 stop
 * Stopping PostgreSQL 8.4 database server                               [ OK ] 
jgr@cagliari:~$ sudo service postgresql-8.4 start
 * Starting PostgreSQL 8.4 database server                               [ OK ]
```

And then again:

```
pg_upgradecluster 8.4 main
```

Errors related with pgRouting were reported.
It took a while (all night!), but afterwards the database was upgraded to 9.1. 
PostGIS was also upgrade to 1.5.3.

Comment: FYI, I found that doing a "du -hs" in the /var/lib/postgresql/9.1 directory and then comparing that with the output of the same command in /var/lib/postgresql/8.4/, I found that I could gauge how much has been copied over based on the size output from that command.

Comment: I know this isn't the question that is being discussed. But I ran into the same issue as you described. The reason pg_upgradecluster couldn't stop the old cluster was because a Tomcat instance was using the connections and Postgres couldn't close them. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

when there is not enough time for a dump and restore, use pg_upgrade:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/pgupgrade.html